# How can I make a mobile webapp work offline on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, html

I am thinking of having a HTML page which references no CSS or .js files outside of itself so that it can work offline. Would this work?

Comment: http://diveintohtml5.info/offline.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use HTML5 `Application Cache`.

Consider starting from this tutorial: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/

Comment: Yeah, but I want a technique that will work everywhere and all the time. What happens if the way appcache works changes in two years time?

Comment: It won't change significantly as it's a part of HTML5 standard: http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/browsers.html#offline

Comment: Or this one is more comprehensive: http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/offline.html

Comment: So this means I will not have to merge any files if I use the application cache? Do I need to add the application cache tags to the javascript files too?

Comment: No you don't have to merge any files and you don't have to add the tags to js files. The `.appcache` file (`text/cache-manifest`) is only applied to html files in their `<html>` tag: `<html manifest="YourCacheFile.appcache">`, and the `.appcache` file then contains a list of resources (html, js, css, images, etc.) to cache.

Comment: If your content pages are generated, it's a good idea to specify the appcache manifest once in a kind of Master or Layout Page.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this will work. You can put all HTML pages and CSS or JS files which HTML references to into your app.

Comment: Do you know if there is a tool that can do this for me which I can pass the input HTMl file source location?